# In Tkinter How do I make a child window that closes the parent but shows all the widgets in the child?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, parent

I am trying to make a menu based application. It needs to show multiple screens in one frame, i.e when the user presses the 'next' button it will clear the output and show the option they have chosen. I have tried the Toplevel method but I don't think it is the answer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    from Tkinter import *



app = Tk()

# Background colour

app.configure(bg='cornflower blue')


COLORS  =['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
    'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
    'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon', 'mint cream', 'azure', 'alice blue', 'lavender',
    'lavender blush', 'misty rose', 'dark slate gray', 'dim gray', 'slate gray',
    'light slate gray', 'gray', 'light grey', 'midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue',
    'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue',  'blue',
    'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue', 'sky blue', 'light sky blue', 'steel blue', 'light steel blue',
    'light blue', 'powder blue', 'pale turquoise', 'dark turquoise', 'medium turquoise', 'turquoise',
    'cyan', 'light cyan', 'cadet blue', 'medium aquamarine', 'aquamarine', 'dark green', 'dark olive green',
    'dark sea green', 'sea green', 'medium sea green', 'light sea green', 'pale green', 'spring green',
    'lawn green', 'medium spring green', 'green yellow', 'lime green', 'yellow green',
    'forest green', 'olive drab', 'dark khaki', 'khaki', 'pale goldenrod', 'light goldenrod yellow',
    'light yellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 'light goldenrod', 'goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod', 'rosy brown',
    'indian red', 'saddle brown', 'sandy brown',
    'dark salmon', 'salmon', 'light salmon', 'orange', 'dark orange',
    'coral', 'light coral', 'tomato', 'orange red', 'red', 'hot pink', 'deep pink', 'pink', 'light pink',
    'pale violet red', 'maroon', 'medium violet red', 'violet red',
    'medium orchid', 'dark orchid', 'dark violet', 'blue violet', 'purple', 'medium purple',
    'thistle', 'snow2', 'snow3',
    'snow4', 'seashell2', 'seashell3', 'seashell4', 'AntiqueWhite1', 'AntiqueWhite2',
    'AntiqueWhite3', 'AntiqueWhite4', 'bisque2', 'bisque3', 'bisque4', 'PeachPuff2',
    'PeachPuff3', 'PeachPuff4', 'NavajoWhite2', 'NavajoWhite3', 'NavajoWhite4',
    'LemonChiffon2', 'LemonChiffon3', 'LemonChiffon4', 'cornsilk2', 'cornsilk3',
    'cornsilk4', 'ivory2', 'ivory3', 'ivory4', 'honeydew2', 'honeydew3', 'honeydew4',
    'LavenderBlush2', 'LavenderBlush3', 'LavenderBlush4', 'MistyRose2', 'MistyRose3',
    'MistyRose4', 'azure2', 'azure3', 'azure4', 'SlateBlue1', 'SlateBlue2', 'SlateBlue3',
    'SlateBlue4', 'RoyalBlue1', 'RoyalBlue2', 'RoyalBlue3', 'RoyalBlue4', 'blue2', 'blue4',
    'DodgerBlue2', 'DodgerBlue3', 'DodgerBlue4', 'SteelBlue1', 'SteelBlue2',
    'SteelBlue3', 'SteelBlue4', 'DeepSkyBlue2', 'DeepSkyBlue3', 'DeepSkyBlue4',
    'SkyBlue1', 'SkyBlue2', 'SkyBlue3', 'SkyBlue4', 'LightSkyBlue1', 'LightSkyBlue2',
    'LightSkyBlue3', 'LightSkyBlue4', 'SlateGray1', 'SlateGray2', 'SlateGray3',
    'SlateGray4', 'LightSteelBlue1', 'LightSteelBlue2', 'LightSteelBlue3',
    'LightSteelBlue4', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4',
    'LightCyan2', 'LightCyan3', 'LightCyan4', 'PaleTurquoise1', 'PaleTurquoise2',
    'PaleTurquoise3', 'PaleTurquoise4', 'CadetBlue1', 'CadetBlue2', 'CadetBlue3',
    'CadetBlue4', 'turquoise1', 'turquoise2', 'turquoise3', 'turquoise4', 'cyan2', 'cyan3',
    'cyan4', 'DarkSlateGray1', 'DarkSlateGray2', 'DarkSlateGray3', 'DarkSlateGray4',
    'aquamarine2', 'aquamarine4', 'DarkSeaGreen1', 'DarkSeaGreen2', 'DarkSeaGreen3',
    'DarkSeaGreen4', 'SeaGreen1', 'SeaGreen2', 'SeaGreen3', 'PaleGreen1', 'PaleGreen2',
    'PaleGreen3', 'PaleGreen4', 'SpringGreen2', 'SpringGreen3', 'SpringGreen4',
    'green2', 'green3', 'green4', 'chartreuse2', 'chartreuse3', 'chartreuse4',
    'OliveDrab1', 'OliveDrab2', 'OliveDrab4', 'DarkOliveGreen1', 'DarkOliveGreen2',
    'DarkOliveGreen3', 'DarkOliveGreen4', 'khaki1', 'khaki2', 'khaki3', 'khaki4',
    'LightGoldenrod1', 'LightGoldenrod2', 'LightGoldenrod3', 'LightGoldenrod4',
    'LightYellow2', 'LightYellow3', 'LightYellow4', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4',
    'gold2', 'gold3', 'gold4', 'goldenrod1', 'goldenrod2', 'goldenrod3', 'goldenrod4',
    'DarkGoldenrod1', 'DarkGoldenrod2', 'DarkGoldenrod3', 'DarkGoldenrod4',
    'RosyBrown1', 'RosyBrown2', 'RosyBrown3', 'RosyBrown4', 'IndianRed1', 'IndianRed2',
    'IndianRed3', 'IndianRed4', 'sienna1', 'sienna2', 'sienna3', 'sienna4', 'burlywood1',
    'burlywood2', 'burlywood3', 'burlywood4', 'wheat1', 'wheat2', 'wheat3', 'wheat4', 'tan1',
    'tan2', 'tan4', 'chocolate1', 'chocolate2', 'chocolate3', 'firebrick1', 'firebrick2',
    'firebrick3', 'firebrick4', 'brown1', 'brown2', 'brown3', 'brown4', 'salmon1', 'salmon2',
    'salmon3', 'salmon4', 'LightSalmon2', 'LightSalmon3', 'LightSalmon4', 'orange2',
    'orange3', 'orange4', 'DarkOrange1', 'DarkOrange2', 'DarkOrange3', 'DarkOrange4',
    'coral1', 'coral2', 'coral3', 'coral4', 'tomato2', 'tomato3', 'tomato4', 'OrangeRed2',
    'OrangeRed3', 'OrangeRed4', 'red2', 'red3', 'red4', 'DeepPink2', 'DeepPink3', 'DeepPink4',
    'HotPink1', 'HotPink2', 'HotPink3', 'HotPink4', 'pink1', 'pink2', 'pink3', 'pink4',
    'LightPink1', 'LightPink2', 'LightPink3', 'LightPink4', 'PaleVioletRed1',
    'PaleVioletRed2', 'PaleVioletRed3', 'PaleVioletRed4', 'maroon1', 'maroon2',
    'maroon3', 'maroon4', 'VioletRed1', 'VioletRed2', 'VioletRed3', 'VioletRed4',
    'magenta2', 'magenta3', 'magenta4', 'orchid1', 'orchid2', 'orchid3', 'orchid4', 'plum1',
    'plum2', 'plum3', 'plum4', 'MediumOrchid1', 'MediumOrchid2', 'MediumOrchid3',
    'MediumOrchid4', 'DarkOrchid1', 'DarkOrchid2', 'DarkOrchid3', 'DarkOrchid4',
    'purple1', 'purple2', 'purple3', 'purple4', 'MediumPurple1', 'MediumPurple2',
    'MediumPurple3', 'MediumPurple4', 'thistle1', 'thistle2', 'thistle3', 'thistle4',
    'gray1', 'gray2', 'gray3', 'gray4', 'gray5', 'gray6', 'gray7', 'gray8', 'gray9', 'gray10',
    'gray11', 'gray12', 'gray13', 'gray14', 'gray15', 'gray16', 'gray17', 'gray18', 'gray19',
    'gray20', 'gray21', 'gray22', 'gray23', 'gray24', 'gray25', 'gray26', 'gray27', 'gray28',
    'gray29', 'gray30', 'gray31', 'gray32', 'gray33', 'gray34', 'gray35', 'gray36', 'gray37',
    'gray38', 'gray39', 'gray40', 'gray42', 'gray43', 'gray44', 'gray45', 'gray46', 'gray47',
    'gray48', 'gray49', 'gray50', 'gray51', 'gray52', 'gray53', 'gray54', 'gray55', 'gray56',
    'gray57', 'gray58', 'gray59', 'gray60', 'gray61', 'gray62', 'gray63', 'gray64', 'gray65',
    'gray66', 'gray67', 'gray68', 'gray69', 'gray70', 'gray71', 'gray72', 'gray73', 'gray74',
    'gray75', 'gray76', 'gray77', 'gray78', 'gray79', 'gray80', 'gray81', 'gray82', 'gray83',
    'gray84', 'gray85', 'gray86', 'gray87', 'gray88', 'gray89', 'gray90', 'gray91', 'gray92',
    'gray93', 'gray94', 'gray95', 'gray97', 'gray98', 'gray99']



# The position and size relative to the screen
app.geometry('500x500+450+140')

# The title of the program
app.title('Maths4Primary')

# The icon
app.wm_iconbitmap('MathIcon.ico')


# Object positioning in the program
# def GridPos:

# I might use the place() method for the screen layout.



Label(app, text="Question 1", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=20,y=20)
Label(app, text="Question 2", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=20,y=70)
Label(app, text="Question 3", bg="gold", fg="blue").place(x=20,y=120)


Entry(app,).place(x=100,y=20)
Entry(app,).place(x=100,y=70)
Entry(app,).place(x=100,y=120)

B1 = Button(app,text='Marks',bg='gold').place(x=425,y=450)





app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far!

Comment: I just want to create a button that opens a new window and closes the main one.The new widow should show all of the widgets associated with the code for it.

Comment: **Again:** what did you try so far?

Comment: When you say "new window" do you mean a new, separate, floating window? Or do you mean you want to reuse the current window, replacing its contents with a new set of data (ie: like a wizard)?

Comment: Yes, exactly.Peter I have not done anything that is worth presenting yet. I am just thinking about how it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to start with a containing frame, and then "stack" all of your screens on top of each other. Then, to show a specific screen you simply raise it to the top of the stacking order.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Screen(tk.Frame):
    '''This defines one "screen"'''

    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        l = tk.Label(self, text=label)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        l.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.entry.insert(0, "this is the entry for " + label)

class Example(tk.Frame):
    '''This is the main application'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # an array of screens, and a pointer to the current screen
        self.current = None
        self.screens = []

        # the basic layout is a toolbar on top and
        # a container on the bottom which will hold all
        # of the "screens"
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        container.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

        # create 10 "screens" that we can cycle through
        for i in range(10):
            screen = Screen(container, "screen %s" % i)
            screen.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
            self.screens.append(screen)

        # create a "next" button to cycle through the screens
        next = tk.Button(toolbar, text="next", command=self.next)
        next.pack(side="right")

        # start by showing screen zero
        self.show(0)

    def show(self, index):
        self.current = index
        self.screens[self.current].lift()

    def next(self):
        '''Show the next screen, or screen zero if at the end'''
        if self.current == len(self.screens)-1:
            self.show(0)
        else:
            self.show(self.current+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand very little of this code, but thank you for the comments. I am unsure about where the code will go for each screen. If I want to put a button on the second page and not the first how would I do that.

Comment: For the purpose of this little example, all of the screens are identical. I recommend you create a separate class for each screen. Then, instead of creating the screens in a loop you would create each one individually.